# Retrieve and store values into db from uploaded excel file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to save the attendance details for each employee into a db from an excel file as a bulk attendance upload , the code below displays Excel Data Imported Succesfully , but does not store values into the db, the line $last_id=$this->mod_common->add_attendence_data($data_user); is not executed , thats why its not working , How to make this line execute ? As this code was written by some other developer i am finding it difficult to understand.

Controller: admin_list.php

```html
 function upload_bulk_attendance(){
  $data['htmltext'] = $this->mod_common->get_allleaves();
   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/upload_attendance_sheet', $data,true); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
 }
 
    function importExcel() {
 //$this->mod_common->delete_attendance();
 $this->load->library('excel');
 
    //microsoft excel 2007
 if(!$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5')){
  die('Unable to create reader object');
 }
    //$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    //set to read only
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
    //load excel file
 
 global $SITE;
 if(!$upload_val=$this->admin_init_elements->do_upload_docs('user_attendance',$SITE->client_logo_image_src,false)){
  $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
  $this->load->view('maincontents/upload_attendance_sheet', $data,true); 
 } else {
  
  $file_path = $upload_val['upload_data']['full_path'];
 } 
 
     $objPHPExcel  = $objReader->load($file_path);
     $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
 
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
  $excelrow = 1;
   $from_Date = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,1)->getValue();
  
   $to_Date  = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,1)->getValue();
   $total_rows_in_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); 
  
  if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E1'))) {
   $dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($from_Date);
   $from_date = date('Y-m-d',$dateValue);
  }
  
  if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G1'))) {
   $dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($to_Date);
   $to_date = date('Y-m-d',$dateValue);
  }

  $start = strtotime($from_date);
  $end = strtotime($to_date);
  $days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
  $excelrow = $excelrow + 2;
  $emp_code_id_array = $this->mod_common->get_Details2('pr_users_details',array('userid','emp_code')); 
  foreach($emp_code_id_array as $e){ $emp_code_id[$e['emp_code']] = $e['userid']; }  
  
 do {
  $shift_excelrow  = ++$excelrow; 
 /*--------------- Moving row wise for each employees data --------------*/  
  $emp_code = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$excelrow)->getValue();
  $emp_code =($emp_code==null)?0:$emp_code; 
  
  if($emp_code<=0) continue;
  $emp_code = str_pad($emp_code, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  
  $emp_id  =($emp_code_id[$emp_code]==null)?0:$emp_code_id[$emp_code];
  $emp_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$excelrow)->getValue();
 /*--------------- Moving column wise for each days data --------------*/
  $col_no=3; 
  for($i=0;$i<=$days_between;$i++) {
   $dt  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from_date));
   $day = date('d', strtotime($dt .' +'.$i.' day'));
  
   $entry[] = $day."|".$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_no,$shift_excelrow)->getValue(); 
   $col_no++;
  } 
  $present=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(34,$shift_excelrow)->getValue();
  $absent=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(35,$shift_excelrow)->getValue();
  $total=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(36,$shift_excelrow)->getValue(); 
   if($emp_id!=0){
    $emp_id_arr[]  = $emp_id; 
   }
   /* CREATING ARRAY FOR DB INSERT */ 
   $data_user['emp_code']  = $emp_code;
   $data_user['emp_id']  = $emp_id;
   $data_user['name']   = $emp_name;
   $data_user['entry']   = implode(",",$entry);
   $data_user['from_date']  = $from_date;
   $data_user['to_date']  = $to_date;
   $data_user['present']  = $present;
   $data_user['absent']  = $absent;
   $data_user['total']   = $total; 
   $data_user['current_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
   
   $last_id=$this->mod_common->add_attendence_data($data_user);
   //Reset array
   $entry=array();
  }while($excelrow <=$total_rows_in_sheet);
  
 /*----------------------------------------------------*/
  if(count($emp_id_arr)==0){
   $emp_id_arr[]  = 0; 
  }
  $this->mod_common->save_attendance_notification($last_id,implode(",",$emp_id_arr),$data_user['from_date']);
  
  $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Excel Data Imported Succesfully');
  redirect(base_url().'admin_list/upload_bulk_attendance');
    }//importExcel() END
```

Model: mod_common.php

```html
 function add_attendence_data($datauser) {
 
 $emp_code = str_pad($datauser['emp_code'], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 $this->db_replace->select('*');
 $this->db_replace->from($this->myTables['attendance']);
 $this->db_replace->where('emp_code',$emp_code);
 $this->db_replace->where('from_date',$datauser['from_date']);
 $query=$this->db_replace->get();
 if($query->num_rows() <= 0)
 {
  $datauser['emp_code'] = $emp_code;
  
  $this->db_replace->insert($this->myTables['attendance'],$datauser);
  $instanceid = $this->db_replace->insert_id();
  
  return $instanceid;
 } else return false;
 
 }
```

view : upload_attendance_sheet.php

```html
<section class="content-header">
          <h1>
   Upload Attendance
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_list"> Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_list#peopleconnect">Attendance</a></li>
   <li class="active">Upload Attendance</li>
            
          </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <!-- Thought Day-->
                        <div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
<?php if($bulkUploadMsg!=''){?>
<?php echo $bulkUploadMsg;?>
<?php } ?>

<?php 
if($this->session->flashdata('success') == TRUE){ 
echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
}
?>


<br>

<?php 
echo form_open_multipart('admin_list/importExcel', array('method'=>'post','name'=>'uploadUserForm','id'=>'upload_file','class'=>"custom-form"));
?>
Please download attendance upload format by clicking <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/attendance_format.xls" class="text-info" style="color:#23b7e5">here</a><br><br>
<table  cellpadding="10px" style="background:none;width:100%;" RULES="ROWS">
<thead>
<tr>
 <td width="50px;">Upload</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
  <?php echo form_upload(array("required"=>"required","name"=>"user_attendance","id"=>"user_attendance")); ?>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<h3>Instructions to Upload : </h3>
<ul>
 <li>Complete the sheet below and upload to update attendance records of all employees
</li><li>
You may add as many rows as needed - one for each employee
</li><li>Enter the start and end dates in the dd/mm/yyyy format only
</li><li>Only use the legend given to enter primary attendance details - Present at assigned office location-X, Absent without notification-A, On Official Travel-O, Present but not in office location-P, Week Off-W, Holiday-H, Half day working-D

</li><li>Use the following legends for entering Leave Details-<?php echo $htmltext; ?>

</li><li>As good practice, ensure that this sheet is uploaded at approximately the same interval each month

</li></ul><br>

</p>
<br>
<?php
echo form_submit(array('name'=>'submit','value'=>'Upload','class'=>'btn btn-info btn-submit pull-right add'));
echo form_close();
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Table : pr_attendance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this way:-**

```
<?php

public function importContacts($id)
{
  if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
    {
        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $f_extension = explode('.',$filename); 
        $f_extension = strtolower(end($f_extension));

        if($f_extension == 'csv')  // for import CSV file
            {
                $file_tmp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
                  {
                    $file = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                    $row = array();
                    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                    {
                        array_push($row, $emapData);
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                    unset($row[0]);
                    foreach(array_values($row) as $r){
                            $data = array(
                                    'gc_group_id' => $id,
                                    'gc_user_id' => $this->session->userdata('userId'),
                                    'gc_name' => @$r[1],
                                    'gc_number' => @$r[0],
                                    'gc_email' => @$r[2],
                                    'gc_added_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                );
                            $this->user_model->add('groups_contact',$data);
                            array_push($valid_no, $r[0]);
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                  }
            }

        if($f_extension == 'xlsx' || $f_extension == 'xls') 
            {
               /* PHPExcel library */
                set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
                require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
                $file_tmp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                try {
                    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_tmp_name);
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    die('Error loading file :' . $e->getMessage());
                }

                $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
                unset($sheetData[1]);
                foreach(array_values($sheetData) as $s){
                        $data = array(
                                    'gc_group_id' => $id,
                                    'gc_user_id' => $this->session->userdata('userId'),
                                    'gc_name' => @$s[B],
                                    'gc_number' => @$s[A],
                                    'gc_email' => @$s[C],
                                    'gc_added_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                );
                        $this->user_model->add('groups_contact',$data);
                        array_push($valid_no, $s[A]);
                }
            }
        $msg = 'Contacts Added Successfully ';
    }

}

?>
```

Let me know please if you find any issues.